# A Vector Problem Asked In A Science Quiz

Tags: vectors

[image]

This was a problem asked to me in a science quiz: *Given |**A**|=10,and **R=A+B**.Hence what are the possible values of **|B|** ?* 
I said that since the angle between vector **A** and vector **B** can be anything between 180 degrees and 60 degrees minimum value of **|B|** will be when **B** is perpendicular to **R** , that is 
$10 cos (30) = 5(3/2)^{1/2}$ and maximum value of **|B|** can be infinity when angle between **B** and **R** will be 0 degrees.
Is my logic right ? Please help!!
(BTW i still can't understand why they asked for possible values,wont it be a range of values for **|B|** ? )

Comment: Sorry for the stupid answer there. You were right. $|\underline B|$ cannot be less than when it is perpendicular to $\underline R$. When that is the case $ |\underline B| = |\underline A| \cos 60^o$. But from the picture I did post you should be able to understand that you can make $|\underline B|$ as large as you wish.

Comment: Yes your picture was nice !!Please repost it na..It will be a good answer!! :)

Comment: Yes B is minimum when perpendicular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\left| \overrightarrow{B}\right|$ is a minimum when angle $\overrightarrow{B}\overrightarrow{R}$ is a right angle

The maximum value for $\left| \overrightarrow{B}\right|$ is infinte, as we can set  $\left| \overrightarrow{R}\right|$ to be infinite

To compute the minimum value for $\left| \overrightarrow{B}\right|$, we have

$$\sin(60)=\frac{\left|\overrightarrow{B}\right|}{\left|\overrightarrow{A}\right|}$$

Since $\left|\overrightarrow{A}\right|=10$, we are left with the minimum value for $\left|\overrightarrow{B}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot 10=5\sqrt{3}$

So the values of $\left|\overrightarrow{B}\right|$ range from $5\sqrt{3}$ to infinity.